# How to add a variable (id) to send when uploading image in CKeditor 4

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel, ckeditor

I'm using Laravel 7. I got the code in uploading an image without the plugin but my problem now is adding an id (variable) passed together with the 3 variable defaults from CKeditor 4.

```
CKEditor=editor1&CKEditorFuncNum=1&langCode=en
```

These are the variables being passed in the "Query String Parameters":

```
_token: PcQGTkcFguEY4dJeguWsaNo (sample token)
CKEditor: pDescription
CKEditorFuncNum: 1
langCode: en
```

What I want to happen is to for the url to become like this with the "id" variable

Sample:

```
CKEditor=editor1&CKEditorFuncNum=1&langCode=en&id=1
```

These are the variables that I want to be passed in the "Query String Parameters":
with the "id" variable

```
_token: PcQGTkcFguEY4dJeguWsaNo (sample token)
CKEditor: pDescription
CKEditorFuncNum: 1
langCode: en
id:1
```

The id (variable) is the id of the product that the photo I want to associate with (foreign key).

How can I achieve this or any idea where should I start?

Here is my code:

Controller:

```
 public function upload(Request $request)
{ 
     

    if($request->hasFile('upload')) {
        $originName = $request->file('upload')->getClientOriginalName();
        $fileName = pathinfo($originName, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
        $extension = $request->file('upload')->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $fileName = $fileName.'_'.time().'.'.$extension;
    
        $request->file('upload')->move(public_path('uploaded_productpictures'), $fileName);

        $CKEditorFuncNum = $request->input('CKEditorFuncNum');
        $url = asset('uploaded_productpictures/'.$fileName); 
        $msg = 'Image uploaded successfully'; 
        $response = "<script>window.parent.CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction($CKEditorFuncNum, '$url', '$msg')</script>";
           
        @header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8'); 
        echo $response;

        // return response()->json([ 'fileName' => $filename, 'uploaded' => true, 'url' => $url, ]);
  
    }
```

Here is code in javascript

```
<script src="{{ asset('ckeditor/ckeditor.js') }}"></script>
<script>  
    CKEDITOR.replace('pDescription', {
        fileTools_requestHeaders: {
            'X-CSRFToken': '{{ csrf_token() }}',
        },
        filebrowserUploadUrl: "{{route('save-ckeditorproductphoto', ['_token' => csrf_token() ])}}",    
        filebrowserUploadMethod: 'form'
    });  
</script>
```

And this is my route: I have tried this one but the id is not passing

```
Route::post('/products/save-ckeditorproductphoto', 'ProductphotosController@upload')->name('save-ckeditorproductphoto');
```

I don't know about the ckfinder but all I know is that when I use the upload name as the function to received the $request from fileBrowserUrl.

Comment: show us some code? and do you use ckfinder?

Comment: @AndySong friend, i did update my post with my code. I hope you can guide me on what should i focus on and study.

Comment: @AndySong Im not using ckfinder. Just the regular one.

Answer (score 0):

if you just need the `id` why not pass it in the `route`

```
filebrowserUploadUrl: "{{route('save-ckeditorproductphoto', [$some_id,'_token' => csrf_token())}}"
```

the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/helpers#method-route) said route helper can take any parameter on the array

```
Route::post('/products/save-ckeditorproductphoto/{product}', 'ProductphotosController@upload')->name('save-ckeditorproductphoto');
```

and modify your upload controller like

```
public function upload(Request $request, Product $product){ ... }
```

Comment: id it with "id" variable
Route::post('/products/{id}/save-ckeditorproductphoto/{product}', 

'ProductphotosController@upload')->name('save-ckeditorproductphoto')

public function upload(Request $request,  $id){ ... }

but it's not adding or passing the $id variable.. 
but ill try your code.. 
thanks for the reply